# How do you authenticate a server to Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, server

I have an app written on Firebase. Security rules and client side code aren't quite enough to make my app work. I need to connect a server to do a few tasks:

- Cleaning up denormalized data that's challenging to clean up using
  [onDisconnect
  handlers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-presence)
- Building additional indexes of my data that go beyond what I can do
  with
  [queries](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-11-04-firebase-realtime-queries.html)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

*Updated (20160611): if you created your project on https://firebase.google.com, the steps access the database from a server are different. See this answer: [Is it still possible to do server side verification of tokens in Firebase 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408684/is-it-still-possible-to-do-server-side-verification-of-tokens-in-firebase-3)*

There are two ways that you can do this: Generate a server auth token, or use a Firebase secret.

**Generate a server token**
You can use the same [token generator libraries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html) created for Custom Login to generate tokens that you can use from your server. You can then provide special access to this server from your security rules.

Here are the steps:

1. Get the [token generator library](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html#section-rest-token-helper-libraries) for your server's language / platform. Node.js and Java servers tend to work best.
2. Generate a token with a pre-selected uid. If you're writing a node.js server, the code might look something like this:

   ```
   var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
   var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator("<your-firebase-secret>");
   var token = tokenGenerator.createToken(
      {uid: "my-awesome-server"}, 
      { expires: <far_into_the_future_seconds> });
   ```
3. Use the token to authenticate your client. Here's more node.js code:

   ```
   var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/");
   ref.authWithCustomToken(token, function(error, authData) {
     ...
   });
   ```
4. If there's no client for your server's language, e.g. PHP, use the token for your REST requests as the [`auth` parameter](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-uri-params).
5. Update your security rules to grant special permissions your server, as identified by the uid, like this simple rule that allows read access to the whole Firebase

   ```
   {
       "rules": {
           ".write": false,
           ".read": "auth.uid === 'my-awesome-server'"
       }
   }
   ```
6. Access all the data, do awesome stuff.

*Advantages*

- This is Firebase's officially recommended way to authenticate your server.
- Your server will respect validation rules.
- The server is just another user. You can use security rules to provide fine grained access to your data.
- Since access is fine grained, it's unlikely a bug in your server will cause damage, like delete your root node.

**Firebase secret**

If you're the kind of developer who enjoys living on the edge, and types [`sudo`](http://xkcd.com/149/) at the drop of a hat, you can also authenticate using your Firebase secret directly.

But seriously, don't do this. It's dangerous.

*Reasons not to do it*

- Just like blindly using `sudo`, it's incredibly dangerous.
- Your
  server will not respect your validation rules.
- Your server full read
  / write access to your Firebase. If it has an ugly enough bug, it
  might delete or corrupt data that is has no business accessing.
- Your
  secret ends up in more places (potentially in outbound request logs,
  etc). You are exposed to more risk if it gets out.

Comment: This is a good copy of : https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html but does actually expand on some valuable points.

Comment: @kapad: That's up to you. They only have to be accessible to the client, so some people use network level controls since they're authenticating users to an intranet.  For other use cases it's usually integrating with an existing login & password.

Comment: Here's the official link for server auth https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server

Comment: @mimming    Could you please have a look at my question. I am struggling to get access to my Firebase database using access token. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810233