# Firebase secret authentication returning null payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-security

I used `ref.authWithCustomToken()`, but the payload that is returned has null properties: auth, expires, token, uid. Except for the 'provider' property which is set to 'custom'. The `authData` object has `null` values.  What is more curious is its **not saying "Login Failed!"**, its saying **Authenticated successfully with payload: null**.

What is the reason for this?

```
var ref = new Firebase(kRootRefURL);
ref.authWithCustomToken(kSecret, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

I took an additional step set an `onAuth()` listener to just log the `authData` to the console but it, too, is `null`.

Comment: I wonder if its a special case in that its because I am authenticating with SECRET.

Comment: If you are worried about not having any authData, you may also consider setting up the server authentication using custom auth as Jenny describes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240940/how-do-you-authenticate-a-server-to-firebase/29240941#29240941

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `authData` refers to the auth. credential payload (usually a JSON Web Token), which would normally show up in your security rules under the `auth` variable, for use in restricting read / write access to your Firebase.

When authenticating with a secret, there is no payload and thus the `null`-value `authData`, despite being authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that. It wasn't until after I posted the question that I figured it out.