# Authenticated server with a secret is not admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I don't understand why my node server, authenticated with authWithCustomToken(secret,funct()) seems to not get the admin privilege :

```
   myFirebaseRef = new Firebase(url);
   myFirebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(secret,function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(currTime() + " [CONFIG] ... Firebase authentication failed!", error);
      } else {
        console.log(currTime() + " [CONFIG] ... Firebase authentication succeeded, authData : " + JSON.stringify(authData));
      }
   }
```

Authentication seems successfull :

> 07:13 [CONFIG] ... Firebase authentication succeeded, authData : {"auth":null,"expires":null,"token":"","uid":null,"provider":"custom"}

When my server tries to update a child :

> FIREBASE WARNING: update at /bd/google:112747494449447764778/9782871294917 failed: permission_denied

My client-side code is authenticated correctly and get the expected permissions.

My rules :

```
    {
    "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      "bd": {
        ".read": true,
        "$usernode": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $usernode"
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

Any hints ?

Comment: Are you sure authentication is a succes? Because auth is null

Comment: Should I not get an error in that case ? Also, any way to debug security on my firebase side ?

Comment: This thread suggests that the auth data is expected to be empty when a secret is used instead of a JWT. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594308/firebase-secret-authentication-returning-null-payload

Answer (score 0):

The url I was refering to in my Firebase object was not the root, but "/bd".
The server does have the admin rights once this is corrected.