# How to generate the Firebase auth token Java?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to write the integration test cases
One of the tests need to send X-auth firebase header

How to generate the Firebase auth token in Java?

Comment: Are you looking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042347/using-firebase-java-library-on-server-without-authentication-process)? Also please check [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/) for Java to [generate a Firebase Authentication token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

In its simplest form, generating the token looks like this:

```
String uid = "some-uid";

String customToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid);
```

You can also set specific claims in the token, with something like this:

```
String uid = "some-uid";
Map<String, Object> additionalClaims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
additionalClaims.put("premiumAccount", true);

String customToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    .createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims);
```

Both examples come straight from the documentation I linked, so I highly recommend checking that out for more details.