# Firebase Token Verification

Tags: php, android, firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication

I have a PHP backend and an Android client. With the client the users can log into my app using either Google or Facebook, both via Firebase. I get the token from the `FirebaseUser` and send it to my server. It is straightforward that the first section (the *header*) contains the algorithm (which is RS256) and the second one (the *payload*) has all the user related data. There's a third section which is the signature of the first two to enable verification on my backend. The problem is, I don't know how to do that. More specifically with what.

I used [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/) to check my token and tried to verify it with no luck. Since the algorithm used is RS256, the verification should be done via the public key. But what public key? I tried with my app's keystore, tried it with Google's certs, but it just keeps saying it's invalid. I understand that the *header*'s `kid` field is the signing key's ID and I should look for it, but I don't know where.

The Firebase docs don't help either. There is a guide about [ID token verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server#verify_id_tokens), but that's just useless because it's Java / Node.JS and it still doesn't say anything about public keys.

So the question is: **where do I get the public keys from?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so I dug into the source of the Firebase Server SDK and found the location of the public keys:
https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

Don't really know why they just couldn't put it on their website...

Anyways, I'm not sure, but I guess that these keys change on a daily basis (just like the OAuth2 keys do), so you must check and re-cache them on your server every now and then.

Also, you have to check the following values:

- `alg == "RS256"`
- `iss`: `https://securetoken.google.com/<firebaseProjectID>`
- `aud`: `<firebaseProjectID>`
- `sub` is non-empty

> Found these at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37492640/2644098) (*just scroll to the bottom of the answer*), which was found by searching for that specific *googleapis.com* URL.

Comment: can you explain please how to pass public keys to decode function in PHP? Please see my question here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098150/how-to-verify-firebase-id-token-with-phpjwt