# Firebase authenticate with backend server

Tags: firebase, google-signin, firebase-authentication

My Android app currently uses Google sign in and this works well. I add the tokenId to every server request and then verify it on the server. This was very easy to implement using [this example](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library) (I'm using python).

I'm migrating this to go through Firebase so that I can easily add other authentication providers. My problem is that I can't seem to verify the token on the server. All I need is verification, no creation. Firebase seems to provide libraries only for Node.js and Java so I ccould use a standard JWT library like [pyjwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt). But where do I find Firebase's public key in order to verrify the token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408684/is-it-still-possible-to-do-server-side-verification-of-tokens-in-firebase-3). The public keys for Firebase can be found [here](https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com). The `kid` field in the header determines what key to use.