# Alternative to Firebase Secret in Firebase 3.x

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need to allow my app to fetch general information available in the Database but without making the information accessible elsewhere. In other words, **allowing only my app to access some data**.

As far as I know, Anonymous login is not an option for me because at a later stage I am login using email and password.

Basically, I am looking for an alternative to Firebase Secret, in order to allow my app to access the data, but not make that data publicly available by making it `.read": "true"`.

In Firebase 2.x the way to do this was using Firebase Secret, but do not know how to achieve the same access without officially login in.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940058/authenticating-with-database-secrets-in-firebase-sdk-v3), but it asks whether or not it is possible rather than alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Secrets are deprecated now, you can find it under Project settings -> Service accounts -> Database Secrets.
Instead of the Secret, you should use the Firebase Admin in your project.