# Firebase Java client with custom authentication

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm looking for a Firebase Java client that allows custom auth.

So I read the documentation and had a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408684/is-it-still-possible-to-do-server-side-verification-of-tokens-in-firebase-3) but I'm still not sure if there is a plain java client for Firebase 3 that allows custom auth with a token.

As I understand it:

- The Java library is supposed to be firebase-server-sdk, which does not have any of the methods in FirebaseAuth that are in the Android SDK like signInWithCustomToken.
- The Android SDK is Android only and not even on maven central and appears to have dependencies on Google's Play Services.
- From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408684/is-it-still-possible-to-do-server-side-verification-of-tokens-in-firebase-3) I took that it is possible to set an uuid for the Java SDK client, but I would still need the service account credentials, this does not work with just a token.

So if I have a plain Java Application that is supposed to be a simple custom auth token based Firebase client I have no library at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

you are supposed to mint the custom token on your server using the firebase-server-sdk for java. You then pass that token to the client and call signInWithCustomToken(mintedToken). This will then sign in the user and generate a Firebase Id token.