# What does Firebase server side verifyIdToken() do under the hood?

Tags: firebase, token, firebase-authentication, verify

I'm considering to use Firebase to perform [identity verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/). I am new to JWT, so my apologies if this is an obvious question, but I don't understand how the verification is actually done. It seems that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken)` works asynchronously, as the result is obtained via a listener. I understand that some [certificates](https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com) are used as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408684/is-it-still-possible-to-do-server-side-verification-of-tokens-in-firebase-3?noredirect=1&lq=1), and that those certificates are rotated regularly. Does it mean that networking is required between my back-end server and Firebase server's *each* time I will call `verifyIdToken()`? Isn't it a problem ?

Comment: I've used `verifyIdToken` on my app when I tried migrating it to Firebase. You're correct that it works asynchronously (and I had a problem with this on my stack configuration). On my setup, `verifyIdToken` will be called on a REST API that requires the `idToken`. Once accepted, it does its usual thing. So for me, a network call will be required between the back-end server and Firebase's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to verify Firebase ID tokens, the Firebase Auth public certs need to be retrieved (network request) and these are rotated on a regular basis. These are needed to ensure the Id token has not been tampered with. The JWT is first parsed, the algorithm to encrypt the token is checked to see if it matches the expected one, the signature is then verified using the public key obtained, finally the JWT claims are validated ensuring the token has not expired.

Comment: Is that a network request for every invocation of `
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)`?

Comment: No, the public certs can be cached. They don't get rotated that often. When they expire, a network request is needed. The majority of the time, you just use the cached ones.

Comment: will it return a new token if it has been expired?