# Share AccessToken between AngularFire2/Firebase and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I feel like I am wanting to do something that is either easy, or very wrong.  Not sure which one yet.

I am wanting to build an application that is backed by Firebase for:

- Authentication
- Realtime Database

I will build an Angular2 Front end Single Page App using AngularFire2.   Using AngularFire2, the user will authenticate using GoogleAuthentication provider.   The Angular2 app will interact with the firebase realtime database directly under most cases.

But I have some cases that I want a NodeJS/Express REST API layer todo more complex business logic and interact with FireBase Database.   What I want to have happen is when the user authenticates with AngularFire2 that the accessToken can be used on the API calls to NodeJS in the HTTP Header.  Then inside the NodeJS Firebase SDK I just authenticate using that token.

How would you go about doing this?  I've been digging through documentation for a while now and still haven't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Took lots of digging, but I found the solution.  I hope this is a useful thread for others to find.

The accepted answer at: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408684/is-it-still-possible-to-do-server-side-verification-of-tokens-in-firebase-3) gives a good lead to this.   Specifically look at:

- Authenticating your privileged workers
- Emulating users or limiting access from a server process
- Validating client identity via security