# What is the purpose of firebase-admin?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I have an ember application using firebase as the database. At one point, I need my nodejs server to have authentication in order to read/write to the database.

If I don't need authentication, I could just do the following:

```
firebase = require('firebase')

// firebaseConfigGetter() returns my webAPI key and other stuff
firebase.initializeApp(apiKeys.FirebaseConfigGetter()); 

// Do Server Stuff
```

But when I do need authentication, I found two ways that work. Both of them use the private admin-sdk key. [So the first](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) thing I did was this:

**Case 1**

```
admin = require('firebase-admin')

// adminConfigGetter returns my private admin-sdk key and other stuff
admin.initializeApp(apiKeys.adminConfigGetter()); 

// Do Server Stuff
```

And that worked. But later on, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37492640/5645583) that this is also fine

**Case 2**

```
firebase = require('firebase')

firebase.initializeApp(apiKeys.adminConfigGetter()); 

// Do Server Stuff
```

Both give my server the authentication I need, but one of them utilizes `require('firebase-admin')` whereas the other just does `firebase = require('firebase')`. So I'm just curious: If I have all the authentication privileges I need by using **Case 2**, then what advantage is there of using **Case 1**? Does Firebase-Admin grant me something other than privileges?

Thanks!

Comment: Admin SDKs have different purpose and capabilities than client SDKs. See [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/bringing-firebase-to-your-server.html) for details.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Thank you. Something like this is what I was looking for.